# linux C++ socket select loop

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, select

I'm having a little trouble with sockets, when looping I'm not receiving data except for the first loop, it's timing out each time. If I close and reopen the socket each loop though I seem to be getting the data correctly. Any ideas as to why?

Example of looping without closing:

```
int socketHandle = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

sockaddr_in serverAddr;

serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(/*UDP IP ADDRESS*/);
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(/*UDP PORT*/);

struct timeval tv;
fd_set rfds;

FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(socketHandle, &rfds);

tv.tv_usec = 0.0;
int recVal = 0;
int sockLen = sizeof(serverAddr);
bind(socketHandle, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, (socklen_t)sockLen);

bool timePassed = false;
time_t startListenTime = time(NULL);

tv.tv_sec = maxUpdateTime;

while(true)
{
    recVal = select(socketHandle + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    switch(recVal)
    {
        case(0):
        {
            //Timeout
            break;
        }
        case(-1):
        {
            //Error
             break;
        }
        default:
        {
            /*Packet Data Type*/ pkt;
            if(recvfrom(socketHandle, &pkt, sizeof(/*Packet Data Type*/), 0, (sockaddr*)&serverAddr, (socklen_t*)&sockLen) < 0)
            {
                //Failed to Recieve Data
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //Recieved Data!!
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of looping with closing:

```
while(true)
{
    int socketHandle = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(/*UDP IP ADDRESS*/);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(/*UDP PORT*/);

    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set rfds;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(socketHandle, &rfds);

    tv.tv_usec = 0.0;
    int recVal = 0;
    int sockLen = sizeof(serverAddr);
    bind(socketHandle, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, (socklen_t)sockLen);


    bool timePassed = false;
    time_t startListenTime = time(NULL);

    tv.tv_sec = maxUpdateTime;

    recVal = select(socketHandle + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    switch(recVal)
    {
        case(0):
        {
            //Timeout
            break;
        }
        case(-1):
        {
            //Error
             break;
        }
        default:
        {
            /*Packet Datastructure*/ pkt;
            if(recvfrom(socketHandle, &pkt, sizeof(/*Packet Datastructure*/), 0, (sockaddr*)&serverAddr, (socklen_t*)&sockLen) < 0)
            {
                //Failed to read packet
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //Read Packet!!
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    close(socketHandle);
}
```

Comment: move the FD_ZERO() and  FD_SET() inside the loop right about the select().

Comment: See this http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/select.3.asp saying the descriptors are modified to show which descriptors are ready for I/O.

Comment: @RichardChambers, you should make that an answer not just a comment, so I can upvote it :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely, thanks for the upvote.  I wanted to do a quick check on the docs to make sure my memory was correct!  LOL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `select()` function uses the specified file descriptor mask to determine which file descriptors to monitor for an event (read, write, etc.).  When a file descriptor is available for an I/O activity (read, write) the `select()` function modifies the descriptors to indicate which of the files are ready for the given I/O action.

See this article on the [select function and the macros/functions used with the file descriptors](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/select.3.asp).

Old style Unix type programs often treated the file descriptor as a bit mask and just checked the bits.  However the actual implementation of the file descriptor can vary by compiler so it is best to use the standard file descriptor macros/functions to set, clear, and test the various file descriptors.

So when using the `select()` function you need to use `FD_ZERO()` and `FD_SET()` so that you will set the specific file descriptors that you want for this particular call to the `select()` function.  When `select()` returns, it will indicate which of the file descriptors designated are actually ready to be used for the I/O action (read, write, etc.).

So your code will actually be something like:

```
while(true)
{
    fd_set rfds;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(socketHandle, &rfds);
    recVal = select(socketHandle + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    switch(recVal)
    {
        case(0):
        {
            //Timeout
            break;
        }
        case(-1):
        {
            //Error
             break;
        }
        default:
        {
            /*Packet Data Type*/ pkt;
            if(recvfrom(socketHandle, &pkt, sizeof(/*Packet Data Type*/), 0, (sockaddr*)&serverAddr, (socklen_t*)&sockLen) < 0)
            {
                //Failed to Recieve Data
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //Recieved Data!!
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

However what you really should do is to use the `FD_ISSET()` function to check which particular file descriptors are ready for use.  In your case you have only the one but in a situation where there were multiple descriptors you would want to use the `FD_ISSET()` function as well.

Comment: Aha! Thanks very much for the prompt response and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

When `select` returns anything except `-1` it is considered success and the fd sets are modified to say which ones are ready or have an error.

From the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html):

> Upon successful completion, the *pselect*() or *select*() function shall modify the objects pointed to by the *readfds*, *writefds*, and *errorfds* arguments to indicate which file descriptors are ready for reading, ready for writing, or have an error condition pending, respectively, and shall return the total number of ready descriptors in all the output sets.

If a timeout occurs, then it returns zero meaning none of the descriptors became ready, and no bits will be set in the fd sets.

So when your call times out there are no bits set in `rfds`, and so on the next loop when you call `select` you are asking it to wait for an empty set, which will never return a positive value because if you wait for zero FDs then you will never get a non-zero number of ready FDs!

You need to remember that `rfds` is both an input parameter and an output parameter, and so ensure it is set correctly before each call to `select`.

Comment: good point about the time out will return file descriptors all off.